# Laravel - Getting a collection from a table using "join" clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

LaraCSV uses Laravel Collections to easily export csv files from an Eloquent Model. The table I'm extracting the CSV from has 3 FKs from another table. The fields are ['Operator','Supervisor','Escort'] which relate to the PERS_ID from another table.

I need to create a Collection that considers the join clause needed for these 3 fields to contain the full name of the workers, instead of just the PERS_ID.

I've tried the following:

```
$excesos = ExcesosVelocidad::all();
```

Which gives me a Collection but does not allow me to perform the JOIN clause needed to bring the full names of the workers. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins like this:

```
$excesos = ExcesosVelocidad::join('x', 'x.x', '=', 'x.x')->get();
```